# Posting JSON data via AJAX to Web API fails with "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32"

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I want to send data from my website to my WEB API my partners are working on via AJAX. The WEB API is a .net Core 3.0 app. And the form is to register a new user.

But I'm facing a problem from parsing the input data of one of my input fields.

**My JQuery script looks like this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#postform").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var apiurl = "https://luna.example.com:44350/login/register";

        var data = {
            Name: $("#fullName").val(),
            CPRNumber: $("#cprNumber").val(),
            Email: $("#Email").val(),
            Password: $("#PasswordValidated").val(),
            ZipCode: $("#zipCode").val(),
        }
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            type: 'POST',
            url: apiurl,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (d) {
                alert("Saved Successfully");
                document.getElementById("postform").reset();
            },
            error: function (request) {
                alert("Error please try again");
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Form Code looks like this:**

```
<form id="postform">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fullName">Name</label>
                    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="fullName">
                    <small>Geben Sie Ihren ganzen Namen ein (Vor + Nachname)</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cprNumber">CPR Nummer</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cprNumber">
                    <small>Geben Sie Ihre Dänische CPR Nummer ein</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="zipCode">Postleitzahl</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="zipCode">
                    <small>Geben Sie Ihre Postleitzahl ein</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Email">Email addresse</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Deine Email wird nicht mit anderen geteilt</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Password1">Passwort </label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password1">
                    <small>(minimum 8 Zeichen)</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="RepeatPassword">Passwort erneut eingeben (Bestätigen)</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="RepeatPassword">
                </div>
         

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrierung abschließen</button>
            </form>
```

If I now hit the "submit" button I will get the following message back from my WebAPI:

> errors":{"$.ZipCode":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.ZipCode

Hardcoding the zipcode will succeed and the data will be stored in the database

```
{
            Name: $("#fullName").val(),
            CPRNumber: $("#cprNumber").val(),
            Email: $("#Email").val(),
            Password: $("#PasswordValidated").val(),
            ZipCode: 6400,
        }
```

Trying to use

```
ZipCode: $("#zipCode").val().parseInt
```

Will prevent the error message, but the value should now be undifiened and thats what the server will return as a new error message. Value undifined (as expected) and Foreign Key missmatch (can be ignored, because value undifiened)

**Output of "data" (without json.stringify):**

```
console.log(data);
prints:
{Name: "", CPRNumber: "", Email: "", Password: "", ZipCode: "6400"}
```

**Output of data using json.stringify:**

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
{"Name":"","CPRNumber":"","Email":"","Password":"","ZipCode":"6400"}
```

**Without the json.stringify I get following error msg:**

> {"type":"https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|eb442172-4475b7c4c9eb631c.","errors":{"$":["'N' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."]}}

I'm pretty sure this is because the "" quotes are missing in the one without json.stringify. But adding quotes manually will result in the same error.

Is there a smart way, to fix that problem ? Because hardcoding the value seems working fine, but getting the value from the inputfield fails. I guess it's because of "" Quotes that are getting added.

Comment: Please include your form code.

Comment: Form code added

Comment: input should end with `/>` and also try posting the result json so we could se what is invalid eg the result of `JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: Updated my post with the information of "data" and "JSON.stringify(data)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use **parseInt**($("#zipCode").val()) to convert to integer.

OR

Modify your form zipCode input element type to **number** from text (`<input type='number' name='zipcode' id='zipcode'>`)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Should have mentioned that my input type is "number": <input type="number" class="form-control" id="zipCode">
But that didn't seem to do the trick. Instead parseInt($("#zipCode").val()) is working fine. Thanks^^